# XML Serializer hasn't methods

Tags: c#, xml

I created a class which should have the static methods to serialize Objects from typ Tool. Tool is a extra class.

```
class XmlSerializer
{
    public static XmlSerializer serializer;
    public static FileStream stream;
    public static object obj;

    public XmlSerializer(object obj)
    {   

    }

    public static void SerializeToolToXML()
    {               
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tool));
        stream = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath
                                       + "\\tool.xml",
                                       FileMode.Create);     
        serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);               
        stream.Close();
     }
}
```

I added the below namespaces
`System.Text.System.Xml.Serialization, System.IO System.Windows.Forms`

My object serializer hasn't the method `Serialize`. I'm confused because in the Internet I find the same way of doing this like I did.

Comment: Where on the internet did you find this? And where is your method `Serialize` in your class. It does not derive any other class, so you should implement it yourself or use some existing serializer.

Comment: does it has method SerializeToolToXML?

Comment: your class has same name as .net's class `XmlSerializer` try to rename your class or set full name for .net's [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: BTW, you should learn basic C# coding conventions. There are several things wrong here: 
1. You use static fields, but re-initialize them every time you use them - this makes no sense whatsoever

2. Your static fields are public, which is highly discouraged unless you have a VERY good reason for it

3. Stream.Close() should be called in a try ... finally block, OR you can wrap the stream object in a `using` block (which is more elegant)

Comment: Okay thank you a lot of. I renamed the class and now it goes right.=) Yeah, I know i must still learn a lot of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your class is named `XmlSerializer`, the instance `serializer` is of that class. If you want to serialize using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`, then specifically initialize that type:

```
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Tool));
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mistaken by having a class `XmlSerializer` that uses the `System.Xml.XmlSerializer`.

Rename your class to something else and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting the line `serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tool))` to create an instance of the class in the namespace `System.Xml.Serialization`. But as you have also called your class XmlSerializer, it is actually creating an instance of your own class, which doesn't have the Serialize method.

Either rename your class or make the namespace explicit when you declare serializer and when you construct it, too.